# When is the first recorded instance of someone dying for a principle?

Tags: religion, philosophy, history-of-ideas

When we think of martyrs, we often go back to the early Christians as the typical examples - dying for the idea that they should worship one God and no other. Another often quoted example is Socrates - dying for the idea of open enquiry. I know that people have died throughout history but I am looking to see if there are earlier examples that fit the definition:

> a person who sacrifices something of great value and especially life itself for the sake of principle.

I'm looking for specific people or groups of people that died a martyr's death (either in historical fact or literature). To attempt to hone the definition further, I am looking for people who placed an *idea* before their own safety or the safety of their kin and who had the choice to act otherwise.

Comment: Incidentally, ancient Christians were martyred more for worshipping a resurrected Christ sitting at God's right hand -- who also had them being labelled "cannibals" for eating and drinking "body and blood" -- than for monotheism, which, after all, the Jews around them were allowed to practice in the Empire (when they weren't instigating rebellions). In fact, Christians were and are accused of altering the foundation in Judaism to get *rid* of the monotheistic principle and create "three gods" in a Trinity not recognized by the other People of the Book!

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, Matta! What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: I posted the spartans example, but maybe you can adjust your question to verify whether that case is acceptable as an answer.

Comment: This might benefit from better definitions. What "principles" and for whom? ["I want my meat and another woman"](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/580365/first-recorded-murder-victim-revealed) would be principles that extend far into the pre-historic past. Anyone facing an invader with "My village? Μολον λαβε" was potentially dying for a principle.

Comment: @LangLangC, regarding research, I put all examples of ancient martyrdoms I could find (i.e. 2). I will adjust the question to ask for named or identifiable martyrs (potentially fictional and potentially groups) in order to rule in Abraham but rule out the other suggestions. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Not sure if Socrates counts as history, but the descritpion of his death in Crito shows that the *concept* of dying for one's principle existed circa 400BC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates#Refusal_to_escape (and probably before, since Paris was considered a coward in The Iliad for escaping his duel with Menelas)

Comment: Must concur with @LangLangC; "principle" is an undefined term.  I'm having trouble imagining a voluntary death (not disease, famine, age, etc.) that isn't for "principle". Every death in every war, every soldier, sailor or marine, and most probably every militiaman, etc.  One might argue that the Vikingr didn't die for principle, but everyone they killed died for principle. I think that this question will be impossible to answer authoritatively.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, I appreciate the misgivings but I don't think the question is without bite. There is something in the deaths of the early Christians, Socrates, and (thanks Alex) Antigone, that promotes some higher ideal that transcends self/group-preservation. Santiago's idea of sacrifice has made me think although maybe it doesn't fit the bill. I did doubt whether records would furnish an example before 500BC, although Evergalo's comment was interesting. I was wondering if there might be an example from Near Eastern/Indian/Chinese myth/legend where we would see a similar martyr-motif.

Answer (score 3):

Abraham and his almost sacrifice of his son Isaac might be a good example. Even though we do not know whether is a real event or just a metaphor.
Spartans at Thermopylae battle are a good example as well. They died because they had to fulfill a tradition (principle) where their society was built, which was to die instead of return defeated.

Comment: I was thinking of Hasdrubals wife at [Carthage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Carthage_(c._149_BC)), but Thermopylae predates that by several hundred years.

Comment: If you are going to quote non-historical events, wouldn't Agamemnon and Iphigenia be a better choice?  You could at least lose the "almost" part.

Comment: It is extremely doubtful Abraham existed.

Comment: Defending an untenable military position to gain time, while it is indeed a sacrifice, is not dying "for principles" anymore than a parent fighting off a lion to allow their sons fleeing away is dying "for principles". Religious sacrifices have been made by all primitive cultures and they are also a different category, imho.

Comment: I can't see who in that story died for a principle.

Answer (score 2):

I think the phenomenon is older than the recorded history. Literature is full of examples, since the beginning of its existence. Antigone is one example from Greek tragedy.

Comment: Thanks for the Antigone example. I don't doubt that martyrs are as old as the hills historically but I am after specific examples. I suspected that there would be many in literature "since the beginning of its existence" but I can't think/find any from Near Eastern/Indian/Chinese literature that predates classical Greece.

Comment: @Matta: sorry, I am not familiar with ancient Indian and Chinese literature, but Greek mythology and the Bible are full of such examples.